# Why is slf4j string format NOT the same as `string.format`

Tags: java, slf4j

If you use Slf4j and the `log.info("The value is: %s", "a_value")` you will get output like: `The value is: %s`. This is totally different from what you might get with `log.info(String.format("The value is: %s", "a_value"))`, being more like: `The value is: a_value`.

I don't really need to know what the right format is, so much as *WHY* the format for log messages in Slf4j is *NOT* the same as the [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for `java.lang.String#format` and whether that's actually still a valid reason in Java, what, 10?

Comment: It's to trick people who don't have the basic documentation reading skills.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an angry rant about why something isn't the way it was assumed to be.

Comment: I read the javadocs, on the method level: Log a message at the INFO level according to the specified format and arguments.

This form avoids superfluous object creation when the logger is disabled for the INFO level.

Params:
format – the format string;
arg1 – the first argument;
arg2 – the second argument;

Yeah there's no warning in there.

Comment: But; the choice to change the format style exists for a reason, I'm sure.

Comment: String.format() offers tons of options for formatting the parameters. slf4j doesn't. Without such a functionality, it wouldn't make sense to support the same syntax.

Comment: @kumesana It doesn't make sense for slf4j to take the very string it received in the first argument, and call the `format` method on it passing it the remaining arguments? It makes less sense to go write a new formatter IMO. Though, maybe there's a reason that was done, other than "sense".

Comment: Also note that output of `"The value is: %s".format("a_value")` is just `a_value` - this is different from eg. python. `format` is static method

Comment: @rkosegi True its a Static method in the package not a member of the class, approximately.

Comment: Funny; I just earned a popular question badge on this question. I do appreciate that a real answer was given: It's better by the metric of speed, approximately 10x. I'm surprised the question itself isn't considered helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the [SLF4J FAQ](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) says, it uses a different format because the format it uses can be processed up to 10x faster.

Comment: Hm; that's a real reason; Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing closer to 4-5 times speed up; but maybe someone else could write a test that doesn't have to call a method to get the result: `String m = org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format("Testing {}", "Substitution").getMessage();` vs `String m = String.format("Testing %s", "Substitution");`